# lim inf and root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

$\liminf X_n^{1/n}<1$ would it imply $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ covergent, where $(X_n)$ is positive sequence.

If not please help me in finding two examples  $\liminf X_n^{1/n}<1$ and series convergent and in second example it divergent.

Note: If $\limsup X_n^{1/n}<1$ then the series is convergent and if $\liminf X_n^{1/n}>1$ series divergent.

Further Question: Can we find above two examples keeping $\limsup X_n^{1/n}=1$

Comment: Note that it is also true that if $\limsup x_n>1$ then the series diverges.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Yes I know I didn't mention because this case itself covered in  lim infxn>1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $a_{2k}=2^{-k}$ and $a_{2k+1}=2^k$ then $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{k\to\infty} 2^{-k/2k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1$$ but $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$$

The $\limsup$ is needed in the root test. In this case $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{k\to\infty}2^{\frac{k}{2k+1}}=\sqrt{2}>1$$

Comment: what about first example means series is convergent

Comment: and can we find these two examples keeping limsup(nth root of Xn) = 1

Comment: @Sushil For the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-r}$ you have $\limsup_n n^{-r/n}=1$. For $r>1$ the series converges and for $r<1$ diverges.

Comment: But in this case lim inf(n^(−r/n)) = 1

Comment: @Sushil You need to ask all the requirements at once. Just put the even terms to be an $n^{-r}$ and the odd terms to be anything else to get a smaller $\liminf$, say $2^{-n}$.